Could there be a “Goldilocks zone” of information density that optimizes complexity and adaptability in natural systems?
In thinking about complex systems—whether they’re biological, social, or even physical—it seems like there could be an optimal “zone” of information density where systems are most balanced, adaptable, and resilient. This would be similar to the Goldilocks zone in astronomy, where conditions are “just right” for life.
Here’s the idea:
•   If information density is too low, a system might lack the complexity needed for adaptation or growth, making it fragile.
•   If information density is too high, the system could become chaotic or overwhelmed, leading to breakdown or disorder.
Could this balanced region of information density act as a “Goldilocks zone” for complexity, where systems have the right mix of foundational (or “fundamental”) information and adaptable (or “non-fundamental”) information? In such a zone, systems would maintain stability while allowing for growth and adaptation.

It looks as if you just throw some balloons into the air, asking for someone who picks them up and provides arguments for your speculations. - Unfortunately that's not the intention of this site. Please see philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

Thank you, Jo. I understand your concern about speculative questions on this site, and I appreciate the feedback. I’ll look into how I can make my question more focused. My goal is to find out if there’s an established philosophical basis for the idea of an ‘optimal information density’ that enhances system resilience or adaptability. I’ll also review the help page to make sure my question aligns with site guidelines.

You could start to pose a question around how to measure information and information density. Starting from a precise definition of the two concepts. - Or a question about the importance of the concept of information and information density for physics. Is the concept reducible? Is it independent or analogous to energy? Under which circumstances does a law of conservation hold? - How does your definition of information relate to the concepts of probability and entropy?

If you are asking, is it possible, then I'm hard pressed to see how the direct and simple answer is anything but yes; however, is whether it's meaningful or canonical philosophical discourse is another question. Philosophers like Luciano Floridi devote their energies to theorizing about information as a first-class ontological entity. Typically in philosophy, information is a mental entity and under physicalism is often thought to supervene on the physical world. Thus, some form of metaphysical necessity regarding the composition of information might be determined by complex physical systems. Ned Block's blockhead argument, for instance characterizes a relationship between physical organization and information and intelligence.
One good place to look for an argument that matches your description is PhilPapers.org. Another good place for hints that such an argument exists and is defensible is the SEP. Here are some articles that might assist you in answering your question and related questions:

Information (SEP)
Biological Information (SEP)
Information Processing and Thermodynamic Entropy (SEP)

I suspect if some sort of argument like you are proposing exists, you'll find at least a reference to it among the articles. Good luck!

You say: If information density is too high, the system could become chaotic or overwhelmed, leading to breakdown or disorder.
The human brain has arguably the highest information density in the known universe.
Sounds about right.

+1 with the caveat it depends on the individual. ; )

If the human brain is one of the highest-density information systems we know, I wonder what other systems—biological or artificial—might eventually reach similar levels. Could AI systems someday develop a similar balance of complexity and adaptability, or will they be prone to different forms of ‘overload’?
